# Creating a function in Python that gets divided until it is in a certain range

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to create a function that will take an input and divide it until it is within a certain range.

Let's say the input is "2600" and I want to try and divide it until it is within 500 and 1000 and then return that number. So it would do this

try 2600 / 1 and see that it's not in range and try again

then 2600 /2  and see it's not in range and try again

then 2600 /3 and see that it's in range and return 866

Anyway, I'm doing this in Python 2 and I think my thinking is in the right direction, but the syntax is tripping me up.

```
def octavesort(input,counter1):    
    if input > (frequency * 2):
        test = input / counter1

        if test > (frequency * 2):
            octavesort(input,counter1+1)

        else:
            return test
    else:
        return test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you *really* want to divide the input number by *every* positive integer until it's in range? From the name of the function, I suspect that you want to divide by powers of 2, to bring the frequency into the desired octave. Anyway, I've written both versions. :)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def octavesort0(num, lo, hi):
    i = 2.0
    x = num
    while not lo <= x <= hi:
        x = num / i
        #print i, x
        i += 1.0
    return x

def octavesort1(num, lo, hi):
    i = 2.0
    x = num
    while not lo <= x <= hi:
        x = num / i
        #print i, x
        i *= 2.0
    return x


octavesort = octavesort1

def main():
    lo, hi = 500, 1000
    print octavesort(23456, lo, hi)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

BTW, you shouldn't use `input` as a variable name because it's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: You were right, I wanted to divide by 2 but I initially didn't see what you were saying. I've been wracking my brain with much harder problems and ended up overseeing something that is super simple. I eventually realized it when my other formulas were not working properly and ended up figuring it out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return the value of the next test.

```
return octavesort(input,counter1+1)
```

Also, you don't need those two `else` clauses; just return `test`.